Azure AI Search Service Endpoint Access Issue
I have an Azure AI Search Service created in Subscription2, it has private endpoint(Vnet2-Subnet2) and dns entry added for this private endpoint ip in private dns zone. From this private dns zone, virtual network link added to VNet1 in Subscription1.
In Subscription1, there is a VM in VNet1-Subnet1 which has python application running to connect to Azure AI Search Service using API Key.
Along with the private dns zone- virtual network private link, NSG group rules are added at the subnet(subnet2) level for accepting the inbound connections, vnet peering is setup between vnet1 <=> vnet2 along with the routing rules.
dns resolution and connectivity has been established with the above setup, even though i'm calling- azure ai search service endpoint with api key, it is returning error message "Failed to get Azure RBAC authorization decision. Please wait and retry your request later.".
To fix this I tried following, but it still resulted the same error:

recycled the keys.
Tried with "API Access control" option setting to "API keys" alone & also "Both" option including "Role-based access control" along with "API keys" option
I tried adding the managed identity to VM and providing contributor access for this identity on azure ai search service.

curl -k -X POST "https://<private-dns-record-name>.privatelink.search.windows.net/indexes/products?api-version=2020-06-30" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "api-key: <apikey>" -d @index.json


Warning: Couldn't read data from file "index.json", this makes an empty POST.
{"error":{"code":"","message":"Failed to get Azure RBAC authorization decision. Please wait and retry your request later."}}

